# Get language alignment?

Tags: objective-c

I need to get language alignment of the device ,which means is it left aligned or right .

So :

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

can help a little bit, but i don't want to go over all of them, or over the exceptional .

Is there another way to know the `alignment` of the language ?
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocale` has two methods, `characterDirectionForLanguage` and `lineDirectionForLanguage` that should help.